# Unable to retain data even using __block

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have been using the AFNetworking library for some time now, and I just ran into a problem.  I used the following code, which uses the GET function to receive data from a remote PHP file.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
__block NSDictionary *data = nil;

[manager GET:@"..." parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    data = responseObject;
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

_objects = [[data allKeysForObject:@"type"]mutableCopy];
```

As you see, I created a local NSDictionary variable and set it to nil, as another Stack Overflow post told me to.  Inside the brackets, everything looks alright; data is filled.  However, outside the brackets, `data` is completely empty.  Any ideas why this might not work?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
As matiboo kindly stated in the comments, I realized that AFNetworking ran on a different thread than the main, which happened to execute before everything else.

I still, however, do not know how to fix this.  Should I make a function to handle this?

Comment: You should read about the queue in IOs. The block `success` and `failure` are executed in background queue after the server response data or not.
The outside NSLog is executed in Main Thread after [manager ....] command immediately . 
This is a related link about Thread And Queue in IOs. I think you should read it first before using AFNetworking 
[link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: Ah.. I see.  Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: I dont know what do you want to do with the Json returned from server.
If you need process the Json return , save it by globar variable ( my be is your _object), write a function to handle it . And inside `success` block,  you call `[weakSelf handleData]`

Comment: I was thinking of setting the variable called _objects (declared in an interface block above the implementation) to this responseObject

Comment: I don't really know much about Objective-C, so would it be too much trouble to put the code for a separate function that I should make?

Answer (score 1):

Your _object variable should be inside of success block . 
Because the return block will be executed in background thread , it requires amount of time, so the command `_objects = [[data allKeysForObject:@"type"]mutableCopy];` wil be excuted before the command in return block(success or failure). So that, data is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is `nil` cause `_objects = [[data allKeysForObject:@"type"]mutableCopy];` will be executed before the `success` block, since the return block will be executed in background thread, which will take some time.

You need to initialise `_objects` inside `success` block. You can do it like following.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:@"..." parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    _objects = [[responseObject allKeysForObject:@"type"] mutableCopy];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Hi; sorry I was unable to respond sooner.  I was still having issues retaining data outside of the block even though I assigned _objects inside the block.  Could there be any other reason?

Comment: If you wanna do something with the value of `_objects` variable, you can put it inside a method and then call that method right after `_objects = [[responseObject allKeysForObject:@"type"] mutableCopy];` statement inside success block. This way you can avoid using `_objects` before even it's get initialised. Hope this will help you.